# How to take mean from month April of previous year to July in R?

Tags: r, mean

```
Month Year Rainfall
4     2010
5     2010
6     2010
7     2010
8     2010
9     2010
10    2010
11    2010
12    2010
1     2011
2     2011
3      2011
4     2011
5     2011
6     2011
7     2011
```

I want to get the average from the month of 4 of 2010 to 7 of July 2011 and then start to get average from the month of 4 of 2011 to 7 of July 2012?

I have tried this code but it worked for the first part only so can anyone help me on the second part?

```
## The code
subdataLGSP<-
  subset(df2.ppt.mon, (Year %in% c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016)) & (month %in% c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))) #Apr from previous year tp July 
Subdatanext<-
  subset(df2.ppt.mon, (Year %in% c(2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016)) & (month %in% c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))) # Apr from previous year to next July 

subdataprnext<-
  rbind(subdataLGSP,Subdatanext)

df2prnext<-
  aggregate(subdataprnext$RAIN, by = list(month = subdataprnext$month, Year= subdataprnext$Year), mean)

library(data.table)
setDT(df2prnext)
n <- 16 # every 16 rows
datPRApOct<-
  df2prnext[, mean(x), by= (seq(nrow(df2prnext)) - 1) %/% n]# This is what we want for seasonal precipitation
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just to clarify: do you mean July by *7 ot July*.

Comment: Yes July mean month 7. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

One line to create the grouping and the rest is standard `R` stuff

`df$gp<- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) x%/%12)`

All together we have:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(Month = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
                               1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), Year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                                                     2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
                                                                     2011L, 2011L, 2011L), Rainfall = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
                                                                                                        7L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                 "data.frame"))

df
#>    Month Year Rainfall
#> 1      4 2010        3
#> 2      5 2010        4
#> 3      6 2010        5
#> 4      7 2010        3
#> 5      8 2010        4
#> 6      9 2010        5
#> 7     10 2010        6
#> 8     11 2010        7
#> 9     12 2010        8
#> 10     1 2011        4
#> 11     2 2011        3
#> 12     3 2011        4
#> 13     4 2011        5
#> 14     5 2011        6
#> 15     6 2011        5
#> 16     7 2011        4

df$gp<- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) x%/%12)

df
#>    Month Year Rainfall gp
#> 1      4 2010        3  0
#> 2      5 2010        4  0
#> 3      6 2010        5  0
#> 4      7 2010        3  0
#> 5      8 2010        4  0
#> 6      9 2010        5  0
#> 7     10 2010        6  0
#> 8     11 2010        7  0
#> 9     12 2010        8  0
#> 10     1 2011        4  0
#> 11     2 2011        3  0
#> 12     3 2011        4  1
#> 13     4 2011        5  1
#> 14     5 2011        6  1
#> 15     6 2011        5  1
#> 16     7 2011        4  1

df %>% group_by(gp) %>% summarise(mean(Rainfall))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      gp `mean(Rainfall)`
#>   <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1     0             4.73
#> 2     1             4.8
```

There are arguably better ways to deal with this windowing problem using `lubridate` package or by converting to a `ts` object.

Comment: Thank you so much for your code.  Your code helped me a lot. But I am trying to get the mean of all the 16th row and the next set of the mean will be from 13th row to 32th row.

Answer (score 0):

Using my own fabricated data (below), here's a solution:

```
sapply(years, function(yr) {
  mean(subset(x, (Year == yr & Month >= 4) | (Year == yr+1 & Month <= 7))$Rainfall)
})
# [1] 0.5421714 0.4412616 0.4867803
```

(for 2010, 2011, and 2012, respectively).

This does not strictly check to ensure we have all months (including 4 and 7) in each range, that's a different discussion.

For explanation:

- `seq(min(x$Year), max(x$Year)-1)`: iterate by year from the first to the second-to-last (assuming contiguous years);
- `(Year == yr & Month >= 4)`: include all data that is in this year and at or after month 4, or ...
- `| (Year == yr+1 & Month <= 7)`: next year and month at/before 7.
- from there, simply `sum( subset(...)$Rainfall )`

The mid-step looks like this (with my data):

```
sapply(seq(min(x$Year), max(x$Year)-1), function(yr) {
  subset(x, (Year == yr & Month >= 4) | (Year == yr+1 & Month <= 7))
}, simplify=F)
# [[1]]
#    Month Year  Rainfall
# 4      4 2010 0.1680519
# 5      5 2010 0.9438393
# 6      6 2010 0.9434750
# 7      7 2010 0.1291590
# 8      8 2010 0.8334488
# 9      9 2010 0.4680185
# 10    10 2010 0.5499837
# 11    11 2010 0.5526741
# 12    12 2010 0.2388948
# 13     1 2011 0.7605133
# 14     2 2011 0.1808201
# 15     3 2011 0.4052822
# 16     4 2011 0.8535485
# 17     5 2011 0.9763985
# 18     6 2011 0.2258255
# 19     7 2011 0.4448092
# [[2]]
#    Month Year   Rainfall
# 16     4 2011 0.85354845
# 17     5 2011 0.97639849
# 18     6 2011 0.22582546
# 19     7 2011 0.44480923
# 20     8 2011 0.07497942
# 21     9 2011 0.66189876
# 22    10 2011 0.38754954
# 23    11 2011 0.83688918
# 24    12 2011 0.15050144
# 25     1 2012 0.34727225
# 26     2 2012 0.48877323
# 27     3 2012 0.14924686
# 28     4 2012 0.35706259
# 29     5 2012 0.96264405
# 30     6 2012 0.13237200
# 31     7 2012 0.01041453
# [[3]]
#    Month Year   Rainfall
# 28     4 2012 0.35706259
# 29     5 2012 0.96264405
# 30     6 2012 0.13237200
# 31     7 2012 0.01041453
# 32     8 2012 0.16464224
# 33     9 2012 0.81019214
# 34    10 2012 0.86886104
# 35    11 2012 0.51428176
# 36    12 2012 0.62719629
# 37     1 2013 0.84442900
# 38     2 2013 0.28487057
# 39     3 2013 0.66722565
# 40     4 2013 0.15046975
# 41     5 2013 0.98172786
# 42     6 2013 0.29701074
# 43     7 2013 0.11508408
```

---

Data:

```
set.seed(2)
years <- 4
x <- data.frame(
  Month = rep(1:12, times=years),
  Year = rep(2009 + seq_len(years), each=12),
  Rainfall = runif(12*years)
)
head(x)
#   Month Year  Rainfall
# 1     1 2010 0.1848823
# 2     2 2010 0.7023740
# 3     3 2010 0.5733263
# 4     4 2010 0.1680519
# 5     5 2010 0.9438393
# 6     6 2010 0.9434750
```

Comment: Month Year Rainfall
4 2010 484.6
5 2010 630.32
6 2010 35.31
7 2010 637.64
8 2010 238.57
9 2010 1129.35
10 2010 376.78
11 2010 282.78
12 2010 324.58
1 2011 338.6
2 2011 859.37
3 2011 66.24
4 2011 38.36 We should get 418 as average value but I am getting 369.12

Comment: That's an incomplete dataset, it does not span from 4/2010 to 7/2011. However, when I use that data, I get 418.6538. For future discussions, data like that does poorly in comments, please edit your question and put it there in an easily consumed format, such as the output from `dput(x)`, `dput(head(x,n=?))` (top `?` rows if large), `data.frame(...)`, or `read.table(text="...", ...)`.

Comment: If you mean that the missing months should count as 0, then ... you need to provide a usable example in your question that states that and includes some missingness in the data.

Comment: Is there a way that I can attach the data?

Comment: 'structure(list(month = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 4, 5, 
6, 7), Year = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011), RAIN = c(484.6, 630.32, 350.31, 
637.64, 238.57, 1129.35, 376.78, 282.78, 324.58, 338.6, 859.37, 
66.24, 38.36), ID = 1:13, gp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1)), .Names = c("month", "Year", "RAIN", "ID", "gp"), row.names = c("4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "16", "17", "18", 
"19"), class = "data.frame") '. This is the dataset.

Comment: Sonisa, comments can easily be overlooked by people who come behind you and want to see if it applies to them. Comments can be hidden, too. For that (and for explicit clarity), it is always preferred that relevant data and code be included in the original question. So as I suggested in my previous comment, please put this type of data in the original question. (That is a good format, just the wrong place on the page :-)

Comment: This is getting confusing. The `mean` of that data is 442.88, not the 418 you suggested earlier. The third element in `$RAIN` (not `$Rainfall`?) shows 350.31 here instead of 35.31 you listed in your top comment. This is why putting solid data in the original question is important. If this is your actual data, please take that `structure(...)` text, paste it into the end of your question, and make sure that the `mean` you are telling me you need is actually what you manually calculate.

Comment: Oh thank you I was putting 35 instead of 350 that's why when I manually calculated was not the same as the script gave me.